# Safari subtracts 1 day from dates before 1300

Tags: javascript, macos, debugging, safari, date-parsing

```
> new Date("1300-01-01").toISOString()
< "1299-12-31T00:00:00.000Z"
> new Date("1301-01-01").toISOString()
< "1301-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
```

Safari Version 6.1 (8537.71)

Mac OS X 10.8.5

Couldn't find any upstream information

Comment: This looks like a Safari bug and should be reported upstream. ECMAScript should handle these dates well, although they are [proleptic Gregorian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar#Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar) dates.

Comment: I upstreamed the bug, but can not figure out a proper link. The bug id is 15724217 (bugreport.apple.com).

Answer (score 0):

The webkit bugzilla repo has a similar report:

[JavaScript: Invalid date parse for ISO 8601 strings when no timezone given](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=89071)

The developer comment states:

> ecmascript date parsing is not ISO 8601 compliant, but we may be able to make this case work.